# Data synchronization between Web application and Local server

Tags: sql, synchronization, replication

our company using an CRM web application and also running our local server(xampp).  There is any Tool or plugin available for synchronization or replication between these two application without lose of any data? please help me

Comment: A lot more info is needed, First thing I suggest is checking the website of the CRM you are using. They usually offer some sort of bridging plugin.

Comment: @norcaljohnny  we are using vtiger CRM [link]https://www.vtiger.com  and also vtiger Desktop application.